# Gallery 2 htaccess deleted while permalink and rewrite plugins active!

Tags: php, .htaccess, gallery

I deleted my htaccess file from my [gallery2](http://gallery.menalto.com/), problem is I have the permalink and rewrite plugins running, now I can't get inside my admin panel to retrive the htaccess code.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how (by what url) do you access your gallery admin panel? try accessing it via `http://example.com/main.php?g2_view=core.SiteAdmin` or `http://example.com/gallery2/main.php?g2_view=core.SiteAdmin` (if your gallery is installed in a subdir `gallery2`) - this should work without `.htaccess`.